# How to use `gcloud builds` for database migrations

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails 5 app deployed with Google App Engine using Cloud SQL for MySQL following their [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/rails/using-cloudsql-mysql).

When I run a database migration,

```
bundle exec rake appengine:exec -- bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

I get a deprecation warning:

```
WARNING: This command is deprecated and will be removed on or after 2018-10-31. Please use `gcloud builds submit` instead.
```

Before I go off on a vision quest to sort this out, has anyone else converted their Rails app to use `gcloud builds` for rake tasks like this? Mind sharing the gist? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Cloud SQL Instances page in the Google Cloud Platform Console. ...
Select the instance you want to add the database to.
Select the Databases tab.
Click Create database.
In the Create a database dialog, specify the name of the database, and optionally the character set and collation. ...
Click Create.

If this isn't what your looking for then try to start over

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43853827/643821) which goes through installing cloud sql proxy so you can run the migration locally:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails db:migrate
```

I'm still interested in a new way to easily execute the command in the cloud, but running locally with a db proxy totally works for now.